# how to change axes limits in a 3D matlab plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, axis

I have a 3-D plot which I want to cut somehow to show the most interested part and avoid the flat parts (as shown in the picture the blue and orange parts to be the least). I think that it can be done using change of the axis limits in `x` but different for `x_{back}` and `x_{front}` which means I want to change the limits of `x` front axis to (-20,20) and `x` back to (-80,-40). How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to clarify?

Comment: oh I get what you mean, I don't think Matlab has a way to have non-straight axes

Answer (score 0):

I think krisdestruction is right, it would be such an infrequently-used feature that it's probably not worth the development time or added complexity for TMW to implement.

But you could kludge it. If you were to rotate your data so that the feature aligns with the axes then you could crop the plot to the region of interest as desired. Then hide the grid and draw a new one yourself.

If you're careful you can arrange it so that you can still use the axis labels at the front, which will save you some time, but if not you can always use `text` to draw new ones on.

I would rotate the data using a rotational transform matrix, which will be pretty quick, and you might be able to pull the gridlines out of the `gca` object and apply the rotation matrix to those too, which would save you from having to compute them all explicitly.

If you expect to do this more than once or twice then you could encapsulate it all in a nice function that works out the rotation angle from a given pair of 'front' and 'back' axis limits.

Then you can post it to the file exchange : )